# HIbernate incorrect grouping from resultset

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jdbc, oracle12c

I'm trying to retrieve an entity and its child entities using Hibernate. It works fine most of the time. But, sometimes, the child entities are grouped incorrectly and this happens randomly. Let me try to explain. 
My entity classes - 

Employee (Parent entity):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMP")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column(name="EMP_ID")
    private String id;

    @Column(name="EMP_NME")
    private String empNme;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="Employee")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<EmployeeRole> empRoles;

    //--Getters and Setters--

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31 + ((this.getId() == null) ? 0 : this.getId().hashCode());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // --NUll and InstanceOf checks--
        return this.getId().equals(((Employee) obj).getId());
    }
}
```

EmployeeRole (Child entity):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMP_ROLE")
public class EmployeeRole extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private EmployeeRolePK id;

    @Column(name="EMP_ROLE_EXPT_DT")
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.threeten.PersistentLocalDate")
    private LocalDate empRoleExptDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="EMP_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Employee Employee;

    //--Getters and Setters--

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31 + ((this.getId() == null) ? 0 : this.getId().hashCode());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // --NUll and InstanceOf checks--
        return this.getId().equals(((Employee) obj).getId());
    }
}
```

EmployeeRolePK (Primary key of EmployeeRole):

```
@Embeddable
public class EmployeeRolePK {

    @Column(name="EMP_ID")
    private String empId;

    @Column(name="ROLE_ID")
    private long roleId;

    @Column(name="ROLE_TYP")
    private String roleTyp;

    @Column(name="EMP_ROLE_EFF_DT")
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.threeten.PersistentLocalDate")
    private LocalDate empRoleEffDate;

    //--Getters and Setters--

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        // --NUll and InstanceOf checks--
        EmployeeRolePK castOther = (EmployeeRolePK)other;
        return this.empId.equals(castOther.empId) && (this.roleId == castOther.roleId) 
            && this.roleTyp.equals(castOther.roleTyp) && this.empRoleEffDate.equals(castOther.empRoleEffDate);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * prime + this.empId.hashCode();
        hash = hash * prime + ((int) (this.roleId ^ (this.roleId >>> 32)));
        hash = hash * prime + this.roleTyp.hashCode();
        hash = hash * prime + this.empRoleEffDate.hashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Criteria to fetch Employee and EmployeeRoles:

```
Criteria criteria = this.getSession().createCriteria(Employee.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("id", parameterList));
List<Employee> entities = criteria.list()
```

Suppose there are 3 Employees E1, E2 & E3, and each of them had two roles -

```
| EMP_ID | ROLE_ID | ROLE_TYP | EMP_ROLE_EFF_DT | EMP_ROLE_EXPT_DT |
|--------|---------|----------|-----------------|------------------|
|     E1 |    1111 |       T1 |      2017-05-01 |           <null> |
|--------|---------|----------|-----------------|------------------|
|     E1 |    2222 |       T2 |      2017-05-01 |           <null> |
|--------|---------|----------|-----------------|------------------|
|     E2 |    3333 |       T1 |      2017-05-01 |           <null> |
|--------|---------|----------|-----------------|------------------|
|     E2 |    4444 |       T2 |      2017-05-01 |           <null> |
|--------|---------|----------|-----------------|------------------|
|     E3 |    1111 |       T1 |      2017-05-01 |           <null> |
|--------|---------|----------|-----------------|------------------|
|     E3 |    2222 |       T2 |      2017-05-01 |           <null> |
|--------|---------|----------|-----------------|------------------|
```

For this dataset, I expect E1 with two Roles, E2 with two roles and E3 with two roles.. This works as expected most of the times.. 

But, sometimes the output has E1 with two roles, E2 without any role, and E3 with four roles.. This happens randomly.

I checked the hibernate.log and see issues while iterating the resultset. When it iterates through the result set it finds E3 four times.. Not sure why. I tried trace logging with dbcp, but dbcp is not logging anything. 

 Log excerpts below -

```
2017-06-02 19:13:45,653 DEBUG  ?#?:? Static select for one-to-many com.test.Employee.empRoles: select emprole0_.EMP_ID as EMP_2_49_1_, emprole0_.EMP_ROLE_EFF_DT as EMP_ROLE1_25_1_, emprole0_.EMP_ID as EMP_2_25_1_, emprole0_.ROLE_ID as ROLE_ID3_25_1_, emprole0_.ROLE_TYP as ROLE_TYP4_25_1_, emprole0_.EMP_ROLE_EFF_DT as EMP_ROLE1_25_0_, emprole0_.EMP_ID as EMP_2_25_0_, emprole0_.ROLE_ID as ROLE_ID3_25_0_, emprole0_.ROLE_TYP as ROLE_TYP4_25_0_, emprole0_.EMP_ROLE_EXPT_DT as EMP_ROLE5_25_0_ from EMP_ROLE emprole0_ where emprole0_.EMP_ID in (select this_.EMP_ID from EMP this_ where this_.EMP_ID in (?, ?, ?))
2017-06-02 19:13:45,654 TRACE  ?#?:? binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - E1
2017-06-02 19:13:45,654 TRACE  ?#?:? binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - E2
2017-06-02 19:13:45,654 TRACE  ?#?:? binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - E3
2017-06-02 19:13:45,666 DEBUG  ?#?:? Result set row: 0
2017-06-02 19:13:45,666 TRACE  ?#?:? Found [2017-05-01] as column [EMP_ROLE1_25_0_]
2017-06-02 19:13:45,666 TRACE  ?#?:? Found [E1] as column [EMP_2_25_0_]
2017-06-02 19:13:45,666 TRACE  ?#?:? Found [1111] as column [ROLE_ID3_25_0_]
2017-06-02 19:13:45,666 TRACE  ?#?:? Found [T1] as column [ROLE_TYP4_25_0_]
2017-06-02 19:13:45,666 DEBUG  ?#?:? Result set row: 1
2017-06-02 19:13:45,666 TRACE  ?#?:? Found [2017-05-01] as column [EMP_ROLE1_25_0_]
2017-06-02 19:13:45,666 TRACE  ?#?:? Found [E1] as column [EMP_2_25_0_]
2017-06-02 19:13:45,666 TRACE  ?#?:? Found [2222] as column [ROLE_ID3_25_0_]
2017-06-02 19:13:45,666 TRACE  ?#?:? Found [T2] as column [ROLE_TYP4_25_0_]
2017-06-02 19:13:45,668 TRACE  ?#?:? Result set row: 2
2017-06-02 19:13:45,668 TRACE  ?#?:? Found [2017-05-01] as column [EMP_ROLE1_25_0_]
2017-06-02 19:13:45,668 TRACE  ?#?:? Found [E3] as column [EMP_2_25_0_]
2017-06-02 19:13:45,668 TRACE  ?#?:? Found [3333] as column [ROLE_ID3_25_0_]
2017-06-02 19:13:45,668 TRACE  ?#?:? Found [T1] as column [ROLE_TYP4_25_0_]
2017-06-02 19:13:45,668 TRACE  ?#?:? Result set row: 3
2017-06-02 19:13:45,668 TRACE  ?#?:? Found [2017-05-01] as column [EMP_ROLE1_25_0_]
2017-06-02 19:13:45,668 TRACE  ?#?:? Found [E3] as column [EMP_2_25_0_]
2017-06-02 19:13:45,668 TRACE  ?#?:? Found [4444] as column [ROLE_ID3_25_0_]
2017-06-02 19:13:45,668 TRACE  ?#?:? Found [T2] as column [ROLE_TYP4_25_0_]
2017-06-02 19:13:45,668 TRACE  ?#?:? Result set row: 4
2017-06-02 19:13:45,668 TRACE  ?#?:? Found [2017-05-01] as column [EMP_ROLE1_25_0_]
2017-06-02 19:13:45,668 TRACE  ?#?:? Found [E3] as column [EMP_2_25_0_]
2017-06-02 19:13:45,668 TRACE  ?#?:? Found [1111] as column [ROLE_ID3_25_0_]
2017-06-02 19:13:45,668 TRACE  ?#?:? Found [T1] as column [ROLE_TYP4_25_0_]
2017-06-02 19:13:45,669 DEBUG  ?#?:? Result set row: 5
2017-06-02 19:13:45,669 TRACE  ?#?:? Found [2017-05-01] as column [EMP_ROLE1_25_0_]
2017-06-02 19:13:45,669 TRACE  ?#?:? Found [E3] as column [EMP_2_25_0_]
2017-06-02 19:13:45,669 TRACE  ?#?:? Found [2222] as column [ROLE_ID3_25_0_]
2017-06-02 19:13:45,669 TRACE  ?#?:? Found [T2] as column [ROLE_TYP4_25_0_]
```

What could be the reason for this? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks. 

Versions: Hibernate 4.2.8, commons-dbcp 1.4

Edit: After multiple retries, we have narrowed down the problem areas to JDBC driver or Oracle itself. We ran the hibernate generated query through JDBC and ran into the same issue. We have also found a pattern to recreate this error - pass random input parameters and it fails the first time. If tried again with the same parameters, it works fine. We saw this error once in SQLDeveloper as well. 

 Here is the query -

```
select emprole0_.EMP_ID as EMP_2_49_1_, emprole0_.EMP_ROLE_EFF_DT as EMP_ROLE1_25_1_, emprole0_.EMP_ID as EMP_2_25_1_, 
emprole0_.ROLE_ID as ROLE_ID3_25_1_, emprole0_.ROLE_TYP as ROLE_TYP4_25_1_, 
emprole0_.EMP_ROLE_EFF_DT as EMP_ROLE1_25_0_, emprole0_.EMP_ID as EMP_2_25_0_,
emprole0_.ROLE_ID as ROLE_ID3_25_0_, emprole0_.ROLE_TYP as ROLE_TYP4_25_0_, emprole0_.EMP_ROLE_EXPT_DT as EMP_ROLE5_25_0_ 
from EMP_ROLE emprole0_ where emprole0_.EMP_ID in (
select this_.EMP_ID from EMP this_ where this_.EMP_ID in (?, ?, ?)
)
```

If the inner query is removed, it runs fine every time. But with the inner query, the results are incorrect sometimes. I guess SQLDeveloper also uses JDBC driver, so this seems to be a driver issue. We will probably try this with SQLPlus.

Versions - Oracle 12c, ojdbc7

Comment: Can you prepare data with different roleId? For each row in DB will be different and we can tell if this date is duplicated or something wrong with mapping

Comment: I checked after updating  the role id and only the employee ids are repeated. I have updated the dataset.

Comment: I have updated the question with latest findings.. It seems to be an issue with JDBC driver.